# Store cell contents from first row of filtered data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro that will automate the generation of a report using data from one tab.
The data is stored in the columns: Date, Shift (Day or night), UnitID, Operator Initials, Unit Uptime, and Comments. For the report I need to sort the data first by date and then iteratively by each unit for each shift. The data for each sort will be only a single line separated into cells such as:

```
Unit | Shift | Operator Initials | Up Time | Comments.
```

Then I need to resort the data for the next shift/unit set and continue through all of the units.  Using two For loops I have automated the iteration through the units and shifts. However I cannot figure out how to copy the data once it is filtered. Using hardcoded cell references I get the same data each iteration (as would be expected).

How do I tell Excel to copy (or better yet save as a variable) the value in each cell that is displayed directly below the header line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to select and copy the data once it is filtered

example:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:D10")SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheet2.Paste
```

Comment: Estevam, that works great as long as the sorting results in data being displayed. I periodically have empty data as the final result, in this case I'm no longer able to pull blank data and the sheet goes to cells in the 200+ row count range. Any way to make it ok with this?

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you want, but you can check whether a filtered table returns any results using this line of code `YourTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering and copying the top row that is shown, you might want to consider just looping through all the rows in the sorted table, copying a row to the other sheet when the unit and shift are not equal to the previous row.